# Populate/reclassify newly created field with values dependent on an existing field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, field-calculator, python-parser

I'm trying to populate/reclassify a newly created field with values dependent on an existing field. The new and exiting field has text data type.

Here is the code that I'm using. The existing field is "L2_LULC_10"

```
def lulc(L2_LULC_10):
    if (L2_LULC_10 == "STL1") and (L2_LULC_10 == "STL2") and (L2_LULC_10 =="STL3") and (L2_LULC_10 == "STL4"):
        return "Homestead"
    elif (L2_LULC_10 == "WL1") and (L2_LULC_10 == "WL2") and (L2_LULC_10 =="WL3") and (L2_LULC_10 == "WL4"):
        return "Woodland"
    elif (L2_LULC_10 == "DL") and (L2_LULC_10 == "BL"):
        return "Barrer land"
    elif (L2_LULC_10 == "GL1") and (L2_LULC_10 == "GL2") and (L2_LULC_10 =="GL3") and (L2_LULC_10 == "GL4"):
        return "Grassland"
```

Comment: You should use `or` instead of `and`. Because you compare the same field value.

Comment: I’m assuming you’re using the Field Calculator of ArcGIS Pro.